# General-purpose repository status

Tags: git, bash, version-control, mercurial

I use both git and mercurial for different projects, and invariably always type the wrong command the first time I visit the directory (`hg status` for a git repo and vice versa).

Are there general-purpose repository scripts that will automatically determine the repository type and then pass the command via the appropriate program?

Getting the equivalent of `hg status` and `git status` in one command would be a fine place to start, though more capabilities (commits, push/pull, etc...) would also be nice.

Comment: Did you try writing a wrapper shell script which tests for the existence of the vc control folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it (untested):

```
vcs() {
    if git remote > /dev/null 2>&1
    then
        git "$@"
    else
        hg "$@
    fi
}
```

You could of course use pretty much any `git` or `hg` command to arbitrate. `git remote` has the advantage of being fast and not producing a lot of output.

Obviously, if you want specific features which are fundamentally different in the two systems to be translated seamlessly that's approximately a ginormous job.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the [HgGit](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgGit) extension to Mercurial will help.